# Seeing differing docker container behavior on AWS ECS (Fargate) to local (.NET Core application)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, docker-container

Update: The issue was nothing to do with running on ECS / docker / linux, rather .NET service validation where environment is "Development" where other test environments used another environment name. A useful article on this was:

https://andrewlock.net/new-in-asp-net-core-3-service-provider-validation/

---

On AWS ECS, I'm seeing stopped tasks, and failures in the logs that show that some DI registrations have failed for a .NET core app.

While it is correct that the DI registration failures are missing, what is unexpected is that the application behaves differently under AWS ECS (Fargate). **These issues DO NOT prevent the docker container (and application) starting up when running from the same image and environment variables locally**. Also running the app from my IDE works fine. The missed DI registrations present themselves as runtime errors. I have confirmed that these runtime issues are not present when hitting the health check endpoint.

Under ECS (Fargate) however, I see the following exception immediately after the service starts:

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
```

I don't see what it could be about ECS that could cause the DI registrations to be verified immediately. Is there any known ECS behavior that I'm unaware of?

Comment: [ AWS container team member here ] Mh.. that's weird. Are you in a position to open a request with AWS Support to dive deeper into what's happening? The message seems to be pointing to an application related error. Can you post how you run it locally and perhaps the task def you use to run it in Fargate? Also what's DI?

Comment: DI being dependency injection. No doubt the error message is coming from the application, I just can't understand what's causing it to behave differently in ECS. I'll see what I can get together regarding the info you requested. Thanks.

Comment: Have resolved the issue now mreferre. Please see update.